# Change "Access Denied. " message in Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception in custom

Tags: symfony

I use symfony 4 framework. I created rest api project.

I want to change "Access Denied. " message in Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception on my custom message.

I found one solution. I did it according symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/access_denied_handler.html

But method handle didn't execute.

Also I used entry point, which found in another questions in stackoverflow, but it didn't work.

Is there any way how this can still be solved because I can't find any solution.

I will be grateful for any help

security.yaml:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/users, roles: [ROLE_USER] }

    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            access_denied_handler: App\AccessDeniedHandler
```

AccessDeniedHandler:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {
        dd('in access denied handler');
    }
}
```

If I dd()  constructor in AccessDeniedHandler it executed, but handle() method didn't execute

Comment: Can you also share your code so we can see if there is something you missed there? Did you get any error messages after trying the method in the documentation? Which other solution from SO did you try?

Comment: Perhaps autowiring is not working. Try putting it in App\Security namespace.

Comment: I changed namespace to App\Security but it doesn't work(

Comment: The documentation does not say it explicitly but the file also needs to be in `src\Security`. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @MartinM. yes I put in directory src. Maybe exists another way?

Comment: You mean `src\Security`? The path to the file needs to be `src\Security\AccessDeniedHandler.php`. If you don't have a Security directory, create it. Autowiring is not detecting it correctly otherwise. And don't forget to change the namespace in security.yaml too.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to return a response instead of `dd()` ? Like this : `return new Response('In access denied handler', 403)`. Also are you sure you are throwing an `AccessDeniedException` ?